# An example to create a training model on real data in AzureML

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Can you introduce a real sample for azure ML and show how can it be possible to see the result of the training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.learningtree.com/how-to-build-a-predictive-model-using-azure-machine-learning/) is a good sample to create your first model.
I should notice that I can't load data from url, as there is a forbidden error to load from url, and I don't know why! 
Anyhow, you can import data manually by copy the data from [here](http://blog.learningtree.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data_.arff_.txt).

Also, you can find the created model which is published here: 
https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Cancer-Model-1

About see the result of the training model, you can right click on the tick (highlighted by a red circle in the following picture) of Evaluation Model. Then, in the opened menu, go to "Evaluation Result -> Visualization".
[image]

After that you can see a window like the following (which shows ROC curve and some related result such as accuracy of the training model):

[image]
[image]

Besides, you can see [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-azure-ml-customer-churn-scenario) as an another sample.